# Unable to implemented Bootstrap 4 Design As Expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to implement the design like this using bootstrap:

Large Screen (lg/ md)

```
First (col-md-6)             Third (col-md-6)

Second (col-md-6)
```

Small Screen (sm/xs)

```
First (col-xs-12)

Third (col-xs-12)

Second (col-xs-12)
```

What I used:

```
class="order-last"
class="order-first"
```

What I did:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">First</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 order-last">
        Third
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 order-sm-last">Second</div>
</section>
```

**Output:**

```
First             Third
Second
```

If the value of 1st is more, it does not output the expected.
Could anybody help me. I am unable to figure it out.

One of the solutions was to add first and second in the same row

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             First
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             Second
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             Third
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

But it does not output in xs

```
First
Second
Third
```

Comment: Wrap your code with `<div class="container">`. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example this may be what you are looking for. I don't know if `col-xs` is being used anymore. I also removed your other classes.

Desktop:

```
First   Third
Second
```

Small Screens:

```
First
Third
Second
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <section class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">First</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      Third
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Second</div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Doing this is causing the problem when Third data is huge. The second will come only when the third column is ended. The second needs to come as soon as the first ends instead of the third ends.